# Prove that $\mathbb{C}X=\bigoplus_{Y \in \Pi} \mathbb{C}Y$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a finite set and that $\alpha:G \times X \rightarrow X$ is an action of $G$ on $X$. Let $\mathbb{C}X$ the vector space whose elements are the formal linear combinations $\sum_{x \in X} a_x x$ with $a_x \in \mathbb{C}$. Define $m_g: \mathbb{C}X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}X$ given by $m_g\left(\sum_{x \in X}a_x x\right)=\sum_{x \in X}a_x\alpha(g,x)$. Then, $\rho_\alpha:G \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C}(X))$ given by $\rho_\alpha(g)=m_g$ is a representation of $G$.

Define the following relation of equivalence in $X$: $x \sim y$ if there exists $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot x=y$, where $g \cdot x =\alpha(g,x)$.

Thus, this relation determines a partition $\Pi$ of $X$. Moreover, if $Y \in \Pi$, $g \in G$ and $y \in Y$ then $g \cdot y \in Y$.

Let $\mathbb{C}Y=\langle y \in Y \rangle$.

**My question:** How to prove that $\mathbb{C}X=\bigoplus_{Y \in \Pi} \mathbb{C}Y$?

I've already verified that $\mathbb{C}Y$ is a subrepresentations of $G$.

Comment: What does "$\mathbb CY \oplus Y$" mean? I don't see how $Y$ is a $\mathbb C$-vector space, let alone a complex representation of $G$. It is just a subset of $X$, a $G$-orbit in $X$.

Comment: They mean it is a direct sum of various $\Bbb CY$s as $Y$ ranges over the possible $Y\in\Pi$, not that $\Bbb CX$ is the direct sum of a particular $\Bbb CY$ with a particular $Y$ (which, as Christoph points out, very obviously doesn't even make sense since $Y$ is not a vector space!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notes you linked in the comment try to express the following:
$$
\mathbb C X = \bigoplus_{Y\in \Pi} \mathbb CY.
$$
Note that $X=\bigsqcup_{Y\in\Pi} Y$ is a disjoint union of orbits and this immediately implies the above direct sum decomposition of representations.

Comment: Thank you very much!